# NameError: name 'xmldata' is not defined

Tags: python, xml, function, jupyter-notebook

This is the code I am using to create a function to import an XML file. I believe this should work however I am getting an Error

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xmlfile = 'aniaml.xml'

try :
    xmldata= open(xmlfile, 'r')
    xmltree = ET.fromstring(xmldata.read())
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('Could not open the file:'.format(xmlfile))
finally:
    xmldata.close()
```

`

The error is

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-0edd7906a4b0> in <module>
 11     print('Could not read from the file:'.format(xmlfile))
 12 finally :
---> 13     xmldata.close()

NameError: name 'xmldata' is not defined
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

If the file was not found then there is no need to close it and the exception was raised before the `xmldata` variable was assigned and defined.
If you are catching other errors, take care of closing the file there or catch another exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xmlfile = 'aniaml.xml'

try:
   with open(xmlfile, 'r') as xmldata:
      xmltree = ET.fromstring(xmldata.read())
      # add all your actions with 'xmldata' inside this loop
except IOError:
   print('Could not open the file:'.format(xmlfile))
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using xmldata in `try` section of your code and closing the file in `finally`, if file is not found xmldata variable will not be defined but you are again closing xmldata in `finally`  that's why you got the error.

you can use

```
try:
   with open(xmlfile,'r') as f:
      # your code
except FileNotFoundError:
      # your code for exception.
```

`with` automatically closes the file need not to worry about it. there is no need to have a finally unless you want to catch other exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `open()` call failed, `xmldata` was never defined. So how can you make sure you close it? This is exactly the kind of thing that the `with` statement was created for. Wrap your `open` like this and it will be closed if and only if there is something to close:

```
try:
    with open(xmlfile, 'r') as xmldata:
        xmltree = ET.fromstring(xmldata.read())
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Could not open", xmlfile)
```

As you see, closing the file has been delegated to the "context manager". You only have to deal with the exception.